# Unset array based on it's key value

Tags: php, arrays, methods, navigation

I am creating navigation with the view limits based on `auth` key value. My code is giving me the desired output but I believe it could be even better than what I have done.

```
public function set_nav()
{
    $nav[ 'settings' ] = array(

        array(
            'auth'     => false,
            'url'      => 'user-points',
            'label'    => 'Social Points',
            'selected' => 1
        ),
        array(
            'auth'     => false,
            'url'      => 'user-activities',
            'label'    => 'Social Activity',
            'selected' => 0
        ),
        array(
            'auth'     => true,
            'url'      => 'user-settings',
            'label'    => 'Social Settings',
            'selected' => 0
        )
    );

    foreach ( $nav as $item ) {

        foreach ( $item as $k => $v ) {

            if ( array_key_exists( 'auth', $v ) ) {

                if($v['auth'] === false){
                    unset($k);
                    $items[] = $v;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Can anyone help me to optimize the code in better way? I am writing one system and this will be the navigation for that system so eventually I am going to write this as a method. Probably array as a parameter for the method.

**Method**

```
public function set_nav(array $nav_items)
{
    $this->subnav = $nav_items;

    foreach ( $this->subnav as $item ) {

        foreach ( $item as $k => $v ) {

            if ( array_key_exists( 'auth', $v ) ) {

                if($v['auth'] === false){
                    unset($k);
                    $items[] = $v;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```

**Usage**

```
$nav_items[ 'settings' ] = array(

    array(
        'auth'     => false,
        'url'      => 'user-points',
        'label'    => 'Social Points',
        'selected' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'auth'     => false,
        'url'      => 'user-activities',
        'label'    => 'Social Activity',
        'selected' => 0
    ),
    array(
        'auth'     => true,
        'url'      => 'user-settings',
        'label'    => 'Social Settings',
        'selected' => 0
    )
);

$mynav->set_nav($nav_items);
```

Comment: in my opinion this looks clean

Comment: @messerbill isn't there any way to make even better and future proof?

Comment: Take a look at the array filter functions php offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

First get the column `auth` from your array with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and filter all falsely values out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Then you can simply do an [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) call to get rid of the arrays, which have false as value for `auth`.

```
$keys = array_filter(array_column($nav['settings'], "auth", NULL));
$nav['settings'] = array_intersect_key($nav['settings'], $keys);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://3v4l.org/PbiqZ)

Comment: This sounds cool. Just one thing is I want reverse output. Means all false auth should be in the result. Any idea?

Comment: @CodeLover Just change out the `array_intersect_key()` call with `array_diff_key()`, to get the difference instead of the intersect.

Comment: wow, seems you have done PHD on arrays and it's functions. Wonderful solution. Million thanks.. learn important thing today.. :)